# Model not posting from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view with a model that post data to controller but after submitting, posted model has default values. How can I resolve this issue?
My Model:

```
public partial class SaleModel
{
    [Required]
    public byte CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(11)]
    [RegularExpression("^(989|09|9)[012349][0-9]\\d{7}$")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(5000, 10000000]
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float DiscountPercent { get; set; }
}
```

I have to submit button in view and string submit in Controller for that:

```
@using EKhadamat.Models.Sales
@using EKhadamat.Services.Operators
@using EKhadamat.Core.Models.Products
@model SaleModel
@inject IOperatorService operatorService
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "شارژ ارزان";
    var category = Category.Charge;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Sale", "Topup", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="card border border-primary shadow view-height bg-light">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h1 class="text-primary">
                        شارژ ارزان
                        <label id="lblDescription"></label>
                    </h1>
                    <h6 class="text-info mb-3"><span class="fas fa-hand-point-left fa-fw ml-1"></span>با 2 درصد تخفیف، سیم کارت اعتباری خود را شارژ کنید.</h6>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-fw text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input asp-for="Mobile" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mobile)" />
                        <button ID="LNK_Charge_Contacts" class="btn btn-info" title="لیست مخاطبین" CommandArgument="TB_Charge_Mobile">
                            <span class="fas fa-address-book fa-fw fa-inverse"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Mobile" class="text-danger text-desc"></span>
                    </div>

                    ...

                    <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mb-5">بررسی نهایی</button>

                    <div id="divReceipt" class="d-none">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="alert alert-success mb-2" role="alert">
                                    <h4>
                                        <span>پیش‌فاکتور</span>
                                        <span class="fas fa-receipt fa-fw float-left"></span>
                                    </h4>
                                    <hr />
                                    <label id="lblTitle"></label>
                                    <br />
                                    <label id="lblOperator"></label>
                                    <br />
                                    <label id="lblMobile"></label>
                                    <br />
                                    <label id="lblCount"></label>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <span class="fas fa-2x fa-coins fa-fw ml-1 text-gold"></span>
                                        <label id="lblPayment"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                <button id="btnCredit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Credit" class="btn btn-block btn-info mb-2" disabled="@Model.UserId <= 0 ? 'disabled' : ''">خرید اعتباری</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                                <button id="btnCash" type="submit" name="submit" value="Cash" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mb-2">خرید نقدی</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button id="btnReturn" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary mb-5">بازگشت و ویرایش</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img id="imgCharge" src="~/img/charge.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="شارژ ارزان ایرانسل، شارژ ارزان همراه اول و شارژ ارزان رایتل" />
                            <div class="ribbon animated infinite pulse">
                                <span>2 درصد تخفیف</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />

    <script>
        $("#rblOperators").change(function () {
            var checkedRadio = $("#rblOperators input:checked");
            var operatorId = checkedRadio.val();
            var ddl = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.ProductId)");
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetTopupListByOperator", "Topup"))",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "operatorId": operatorId
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    ddl.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (i, option) {
                        ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(option.id).html(option.name).data("desc", option.desc));
                    });
                }
            })
        });
        --jquery code for show/hide elements or get data from controller
    </script>
}
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual IActionResult Sale(SaleModel saleModel, string submit)
{
    switch (submit)
    {
        case "Cash":
            
            break;
        case "Credit":
            break;
    }
    
    return View();
}
```

for example after submitting form, productid=0 and mobile is empty.

Comment: Can you show us  the view codes that submit the data?

Comment: Do I need special settings for access model in controller?

Comment: Is your SaleModel initially filed when your controller gets the page?

Comment: @HosseinPour, have you debug the codes, I pasted your codes and I could get the `mobile` value on my side.

Comment: I also get mobile value when try to reproduce your case and no properties to bind productid so it'll be default = 0, please check again

Comment: I have another inputs like radiobuttonlist and dropdownlist for another attributes and I removed them from post and I replaced them with ... . I have some jquery code that run on button click, etc like above.
Initialize model and set some of attribute like default discount = 2 -> call view with model -> fill form -> post model to controller

Comment: Did You try to see what data in the body of the POST requwst is sent? If any, did You try to see if those values are available in HttpContext inside the controller? It's a partial class - does it has a public default constructor? Could You try to force binding of individual parts (like for `submit`)? Firstly I would try to see if those values are there for binding or if the class is a problem. Other said that this code is running. What they disn't have, while running it, is the rest of the partial class so try to pass parameters without that model maybe? For starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a button before submit buttons and on click form validation occurred and model was being cleaned. I changed  button type to submit and used form validation in controller.